# Do I understand the definition of limit existence at a point, the definition of continuity at a point, and the difference between them?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, continuity

I am trying to make sure I understand the definition of limit existence at a point, the definition of continuity at a point, and the exact difference between the two definitions. So below I state the definitions as I understand them, and I hope that someone can tell me whether or not the definitions I have given are correct, specifically if what I have identified as the difference between them is correct.

The limit $L$ of a function $f$ exists at a point $p$ if and only if:

**$\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists\delta>0$ such that if $x$ is in the *punctured* $\delta$-neighbourhood of $p$, then $f(x)$ must be in the given $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $L$** (because $x$ is never equal to $p$, it doesn't matter if the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood does or does not contain $L$, nor what the value of $L$ is, aslong as it is a real number).

A function $f$ is continuous at a point $p$ if and only if:

**$\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists\delta>0$ such that if $x$ is in the *unpunctured* $\delta$-neighbourhood of $p$, then $f(x)$ must be in the given $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $L$** (because $p$ must be contained in every $\delta$-neighbourhood we can create, this implies that all $\epsilon$-neighbourhoods we choose must always contain $f(p)$, and thus $f(p)$ must exist, and $f(p)$ must be equal to $L$, if the statement is to hold true).

Is my understanding correct? Are the two definitions essentially identical except for whether or not the $\delta$-neighbourhood is punctured?

EDIT:

From Vincent Batens' answer I have learned that **my understanding of the first definition (the limit definition) is wrong**; the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood *must* be unpunctured because there are many situations in which the punctured $\delta$-neighbourhood contains an $x$ value such that $f(x)=L$. For example, if $f(x)$ is a constant function.. or if $f(x)$ is constant in a neighbourhood around $L$.. or if we have something like the case of $\lim_{x\to0}x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=0$ where $f(x)$ hits $L$ at an ever-increasing frequency as $x$ approaches $0$.

Essentially, in any situation where we can have $f(x)=L$ for $x$-values inside the punctured $\delta$-neighbourhood, the limit definition as I have described it breaks down and doesn't work as it should; the definition would say that the limit doesn't exist when it clearly does. Thus it is not true that "it doesn't matter if the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood does or does not contain $L$".. there are many cases in which it *does* matter, and so we should specify that, in general, the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood must be unpunctured, so that we account for such cases in our definition.

And of course when we have $f(x)\ne L$ for all $x$ in any punctured $\delta$-neighbourhood of $p$ we can create, then the fact that there is an $L$ sitting in every $\epsilon$-neighbourhood given has no bearing on the limit statement; it does no harm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite correct. The $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood needs to be unpunctured (it matters) since for example $lim_{x\to5} 1 = 1$. In any neighbourhood of $x=5$ the constant function $f(x) = 1$ will be equal to $1 (=L)$, but it only matters if there exists a neighbourhood of $x$ where the function is constant.

For the continuïty, you don't define $L$. To make it correct, just replace that $L$ with $f(p)$. (The function is by definition not continuous if $f(p)$ doesn't exist).

Continuïty of the function $f$ in the point $p$ means $$\lim_{x\to p}f(x) = f(p),$$

or in other words: if $x$ gets close to $p$, $f(x)$ gets close to $f(p)$. It basically means that the function doesn't make a "jump" (a *discontinuity*) in the point $p$.

This will hopefully make it easier to think about continuity and what it means.

Edit: To clarify, there are functions that aren't constant on any interval for which the $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood will need to be unpunctured as well. For example $$f(x)=x\sin\frac{1}{x}.$$
We have $\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\frac{1}{x}=0$, but this function will have an infinite amount of zeros (places where $f(x) =L$) in any neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm trying to understand it once step at a time. In the first paragraph (I assume you're talking about the limit definition), what you're saying is that the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood must contain $L$ so that we account for the case in which $f$ is a constant function? Otherwise however, the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood doesn't need to contain $L$ for the limit definition to work?

Comment: I edited to give a better example, your function can be constant on its whole domain, constant part of its domain or oscilate infinitely many times in a neighbourhood. In all of those cases. You need in all of these cases the neighbourhood to be unpunctured. These should be all cases where you need that.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. As for the continuity definition, I don't understand why the $\delta$-neighbourhood *must* be punctured. Couldn't we say that the $\delta$-neighbourhood is unpunctured, i.e, contains $p$, and from that it is implied that $f(p)$ is the value being approached by the limit, i.e, $L=f(p)$?

Comment: I think fundamentally what I'm trying to ask is if saying that "the $\delta$-neighbourhood must be unpunctured" is the same as saying that "$L=f(p)$".

Comment: I made a little mistake, it doesn't need to be punctured, but the definitions with unpunctured and punctured neighbourhoods in this case are equivalent (because if $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=f(p)$, then $f(p)$ will obviously be in any neighbourhood of $f(p)$). In most text books, it is defined as punctured since it is much more natural to define and understand it as a limit, like I wrote in my answer. I will correct it in my answer. (Can you also mark my answer as the answer to your question if you think it is? It's annoying not being able to comment on other people's posts, I need only 7 more rep :))

Comment: Ok, so I understand then that the second definition is fine (albeit unusual/overly complicated), but the first definition (the limit definition) is wrong because the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood must be unpunctured. And yes, I'll mark your answer, thank you for the extended help.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach:

Assume that $~\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L.~$

That is, assume that the limit exists and equals $~L.$

Then $~f(x)~$ is continuous at $~x = a~$ if and only if both of the following are true:

- The value $~x = a~$ is in the domain of the function $~f(x).$ 
  That is, the function $~f(x)~$ is defined at $~x=a.$
- $~f(a) = L.$

**Note**:
If the limit as $~x~$ approaches $~a~$ of $~f(x)~$ does not exist, then the function $~f(x)~$ can not be continuous at the value $~x=a.$

Comment: Do you mean that the definition I used is correct? That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @MahdiRkioui I intentionally left your specific question unanswered for two reasons: (1) Vincent Batens already addressed your specific question, which makes your posting **open season** for alternative perspectives. (2) I (subjectively) feel that your approach is overcomplicating.  I feel that the better (i.e. simpler) approach to defining continuity is the approach expressed in my answer.